# iOS - how to change Documents directory

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, jailbreak

Currently the program I am working on uses Core Data, and stores "Account" information in a file called `Accounts.sqlite`  This file is stored in the `Documents` directory inside the long string of characters, i.e. `A89C1398-A7BE-44F1-A337-DABA9C66AF1D`  So I want to save / create the file for the application in `/var/mobile/Library/KegCop`  I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065585/cydia-app-documents-folder-not-created) and I made the necessary changes, deleted my app off the phone, clicked the `Run` button in Xcode and the app built and ran fine.  However the `Accounts.sqlite` file was still in the `Documents` directory.

I added / modified the follow code to the `AppDelegate.m` file,

```
// default sqlite file path
// NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.sqlite"];

// jailbroken path - /var/mobile/Library/KegCop/
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *docPath = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.sqlite"]];
```

and then created the following method in the `AppDelegate.m` file,

```
// set path for documents in jailbreak environment
+(NSString *)documentsDirectoryPath
{
#ifdef JAILBREAK

NSString *documentPath =@"/var/mobile/Library/KegCop";

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentPath])
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:documentPath
                              withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                               attributes:nil
                                                    error:NULL];
}

return documentPath;

#else

NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
return [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

#endif
}
```

Comment: I cannot see that you actually use the `documentsDirectoryPath` method to compute the `storeURL`.

Comment: Btw it won't compile because of typo in `NSFIleManager`. Are you sure that `JAILBREAK` is defined?

Comment: @MartinR I was wondering about that?  How would I go about defining `JAILBREAK`?

Comment: If your project uses a precompiled header (.pch) file, then add `#define JAILBREAK` to that file.

Comment: @MartinR it indeed does use the `.pch` file.  I added `#define JAILBREAK` to the end of the file, and now the program is crashing when it starts.

I'm getting the following errors,

2012-08-05 10:46:16.924 KegCop[1265:707] Initializing IntelliStatusBarIcons v0.93
2012-08-05 10:46:16.941 KegCop[1265:707]  Initialized listener for icon updates
Couldn't register com.chrisrjones.KegCop with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.

Comment: I closed the process running on the phone, and then tried running the program again and it just crashes at startup.

Comment: I have the same problem sometimes with Xcode. The only solution seems to be to reboot your computer.

Comment: reboot the computer? really? I'll try restarting Xcode, and if that doesn't work then I'll try restarting the computer.

Comment: I rebooted, then clicked `Run` in Xcode, and I am still getting the same crash :-/

Comment: I know only that `Couldn't register XXX with the bootstrap server` is a well-known problem, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788277/iphone-strange-error-when-testing-on-simulator. For crashes in your code you should use the debugger to localize the problem.

Comment: the only thing I can think of is that I added the `#define JAILBREAK` to the .pch and now I am getting this error. :-/

Comment: @MartinR, I restarted the phone, and now the app isn't crashing at launch (yay).  However the `Accounts.sqlite` file is still being created in the `Documents` folder.  I added the code listed above, and I added `#define JAILBREAK` to the `.pch` file.  I also deleted the app from the phone, and then clicked `Run` in Xcode to build and run the app on the device again, and then I ssh into the phone and check to see if the `Accounts.sqlite` is being created in the `Documents` folder and it is (sigh).

Comment: Please read my first comment again! Use the debugger to check the value of `storeURL`!

Comment: @MartinR, Ahh, I see what your saying, in order to use the newly created method, would i do something like

`NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.sqlite"]];`