# Jailbreak - relocate "Documents" directory for Core Data app

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, jailbreak

I made a Core Data application, and I want to save the `file.sqlite` to a different directory from the default.  I came across this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065585/cydia-app-documents-folder-not-created), then posted [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812576/ios-how-to-change-documents-directory), and the project appears to be compling, but my the `file.sqlite` is not getting saved in the location I specified.  I created a method, and added some code to the `AppDelegate.m` file, but the `storeURL` variable is still saving the `file.sqlite` in the default "Documents directory.  How do I call the method I created within the `AppDelegate.m` file to specify the proper location for the `storeURL` variable?

Should I just change,

```
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.sqlite"]];
```

to

```
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.sqlite"]];
```

Also will this break iOS Simulator support?

Comment: I am sorry if this sounds rude, but I think everything has been said in the comments to your previous question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812576/ios-how-to-change-documents-directory]. If you don't know how to call your own method `documentsDirectoryPath` and if you do not use the debugger to find out why your `storeURL` is wrong, than we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by keeping the default *documents* path for the simulator, and then setting up a different *documents* path for the device.  The following code is in my *AppDelegate.m* file

```
// add conditional code for simulator and iDevice
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *docPath = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.sqlite"]];
#else
// jailbroken path - /var/mobile/Library/KegCop/
NSString *docPath = self.documentsDirectoryPath;

NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.sqlite"]];
#endif
```